# Why are loggers static?

Tags: c#, multithreading, logging

I am wondering why Loggers such as NLog have a static implementation?
From what I understand, using "static" is often bad practice as it prevents multi-threading.

I understand that we want to prevent several methods to access the same logger simultaneously, but by doing so, don't we also prevent different loggers from running in parallel?

Is there something I am not getting?

Here is a code example to emphasise the problem:

```
public static class LogUtils
{     
    ...
       
    public static void SetupLogging(string appName, string logFileName)
    {
        var target = (FileTarget)LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName("f");

        _logFileName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(logFileName) ? GetFileName(appName): logFileName;
        target.FileName = _logFileName;
        LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
    }
}
```

Comment: Static does not prevent multi-threading. Modifying shared state can =)

Comment: @Guru Stron, thanks, but if it is static/singleTone, only one thread can access the logger at a time, right? So, how is that not preventing Multi-Threading? Sorry, that's probably what you meant :-)

Comment: No, `static` does not prevent multiple thraeds to kick in simultaneously. `lock` does however.

Comment: @HimBromBeere. So you are saying I could write two different logs in 2 different threads simultaneously using NLog?

Comment: I suppose you could.

Comment: Thanks guys, I guess I need to find an example to emphasise that :-)

Comment: @stackMeUp it depends on logger implementation. For example usually you will want only one thread writing to the same file simultaneously (for obvious reasons). AFAIK at least some loggers deffer writing log to file by introducing some concurrent queue/buffer.

Comment: All logging frameworks that I know of are thread-safe: it would be a poor logging framework which wasn't! How they handle this internally varies (and is sometimes configurable), but you can be confident that you can use a static LogManager to grab two loggers and use them at the same time from two threads

Comment: Generally you want all your logging to go to a single log output, so that's the default. But you can use multiple loggers with NLog: you need to specify multiple loggers in the config file and then use [`LogManager.GetLogger()`](https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.3.0/html/M_NLog_LogManager_GetLogger.htm) to get at them. So although `LogManager.GetLogger()` is static, the logger that it returns is clearly NOT a static class.

Comment: Personally, nlog and log4net, are old hat. I would personally go for something that is a little more modern, structured and DI

Comment: It all makes sense, tx :-)

Comment: @00110001 Using DI with a logger is not necessarily a good idea, since it's cross-cutting concern. Notwithstanding that, it's perfectly possible to use DI with NLog.

Comment: @MatthewWatson yeah there are few schools of thought about that, personally, runtime (non bal) libraries rarely should need to be logged, as they are thoroughly united tested, elide or throw or wrap exceptions. Id make the case for, if you need a static logger because it cant be injected, there is *likely* larger architectural, maintenance or design problems. anyway 2 cents given

Comment: FYI, the reason we don't like `static` is because it limits our ability to re-use code and to test code. (E.g., It's difficult or impossible to provide [_test doubles_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_double) for `static` objects.)

Answer (score 2):

`Static` does in no way guarantee thread-safety. Imagine you have a static method that writes to a file:

```
static Write() { myFile.WriteChanges; }
```

Now when multiple threads acces that method, they would write to the exact same file simultaneously - which would be a great mess. That´s why the `lock`-keyword exists:

```
static Write() { lock(whatever) myFile.WriteChanges; }
```

Now only a single thread can access the same resource. Others have to wait.

logging-Managers are in no way different. Usually you want all your logging to go to the same file, so they rely on internal locking of that shared resource in some way. However that has nothing to do with the manager itself being a singleton. You could lock on a specific resource from multiple instances of the logger as well.

In short: `static` only means there is no instance involved in calling a specific member. `lock` on the other hand focuses on shared resources such as files. Those two things have nothing in common.

Answer (score -2):

Because Logging is implemented as [SingleTon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), that means, you should have 1 and only 1 instance of the logger no matter how many objects are using that at any given time.

Comment: And what does this have to do with multi-threading?

Comment: @HimBromBeere nothing... that is why am not mentioning it in the answer am writing,...

Comment: But OP specifically asks for multi-threading, not what `static` means - even though this causes OPs mis-understanding.

Comment: Also, the question was about `static`, not `singleton`.